# API that removes unnecessary words

Tags: php

I want to search

> Before: Who was the first Russian astronaut to do spacewalk

Converted to

> After: First Russian astronaut spacewalk

Any API that would allow me to convert the before sentence to after sentence? Here are some more sample questions

> Q: Who invented the paper clip? to   invented paper clip
>   Q: Who invented the electric guitar? to invented electric guitar
>   Q: Who was the president of Vichy France? to president of Vichy France
>   Q: Who is buried in the great pyramid of Giza? to buried pyramid Giza

Comment: And logic is...? Cut out first 3 words and make first letter uppercase? Oh, and random two words in middle.

Comment: Something that could point you into a direction: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/extract-keywords-text-string-php

Comment: You don't need an API for this - just do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is a so called stopword-list for the English language. You need to remove all stopwords from your text in order get what you want. You can find a proper stopword-list as an PHP array [here](http://norm.al/2009/04/14/list-of-english-stop-words/)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, let me test it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a list of prepositions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions